# missing squid in /etc/init.d

Tags: squid

I installed squid v3 on ubuntu 13.  Running squid3 -v responds with version 3.3.8 (yet I cannot find any squid script in /etc/init.d).  I am able to run

```
service squid3 restart
```

(process shows as running).  Any insight as to what I might have configured incorrectly?  I noticed the missing squid after I made a change to the squid.conf file.
Thanks in advance.

---

I realized that squid was generating the squid.conf file in /etc/init & not /etc/init.d - I had installed squid via sudo apt-get install squid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squid Installation generates the squid.conf file in /etc/init & not /etc/init.d on ubuntu - I had installed squid via sudo apt-get install squid.

Answer (score 3):

Your Ubuntu release uses already Upstart for starting services.  That's why you can't find the init script for squid anymore in /etc/init.d/.  Instead, you have to start squid via

```
sudo service squid3 start
```

BTW, you cannot use `su` here to become root and then call `service squid3 start`. For more information see [Ubuntu bug #1303769](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1303769).

The script /etc/init/squid3.conf is the init script used by upstart and nothing we should normally edit.

Instead, use /etc/squid3/squid.conf for setting your configuration options.

Answer (score 3):

Service startup file for squid is **/etc/init/squid.conf** 
 this services run as upstart which is very good to restart them use this

commands

To stop

> sudo stop squid3

To start

> sudo start squid3

To check status

> initctl list

main advantage here is system boots faster and also if some kills the pid of squid3 kernel automatically restarts squid3 services in fraction of seconds with new pid.

for more information about [upstart services](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

Below you will see in the **/var/log/syslog** messages

Apr 22 12:00:48 proxy02 kernel: [5864996.503368] init: squid3 main process (318) killed by KILL signal

Apr 22 12:00:48 proxy02 kernel: [5864996.503379] init: squid3 main process ended, respawning

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in /etc/rc.d/init.d/

Your .conf file should be located in /etc/squid/squid.conf

Comment: thanks for sharing - there is no /etc/rc.d directory on this computer.  I am aware of the conf file - I am making changes to it for testing purposes.