# squid3 and no start process

Tags: services, squid

In ubuntu 14.04, I have installed `squid3`, can start/stop it (working fine) via:

```
service squid3 start|stop
```

But i do not see any squid* file in `/etc/init.d/` and `/etc/rc.d/`.
How is that possible ? How service command is working and finding a service ?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Try see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/433803/missing-squid-in-etc-init-d

Answer (score 0):

squid3 does not have any file in `/etc/init.d/`

Service startup script file for squid is in :

```
/etc/init/squid3.conf
```

Different programs use different ways of starting up.
Not every program that you can start stop is going to be in `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: So - how can i control that script ? Where can i find it ? How service command is finding it ? Which directory is it searching ? I always believed "service" command was always looking only in /etc/init.d. If now what are the other dirs/files and how to control that ?

Comment: @user2913139 You have just been told where the file is. `/etc/init/squid3.conf`

Comment: @user2913139 i don't understand your question.  you can control that script by using `service` command `sudo service squid3 start|stop|restart` what do you mean by control ?